# Not able to map composite key with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate; in my recent task I have been asked to create m_department table and use the existing BSU_EMPLOYEE table which has the  composite key (each department can have multiple employees). When I tried mapping these two entities in third mapping table "m_department_employees" I am getting this error. Could some one help me please?

> **org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(MemberInternalKey, EmployeeInternalKey) of com.retalix.insync.mdmapi.model.DepartmentEntity.employees referencing com.retalix.insync.mdmapi.model.DepartmentEmployeeEntity not mapped to a single property**

---

### mapping table m_department_employees structure

```
    [department_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MemberInternalKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeInternalKey] [int] NOT NULL
```

### m_department table structure

[image]

### BSU_EMPLOYEE TABLE STRUCTURE

[image]

### ENTITY CLASS FOR m_department table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "m_department")
public class DepartmentEntity extends BaseEntityDto {   


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "m_department_employees",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "department_id"),inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "MemberInternalKey",referencedColumnName="MemberInternalKey")
                                                                                                                      ,@JoinColumn(name = "EmployeeInternalKey",referencedColumnName = "EmployeeInternalKey")   })
    private Collection<DepartmentEmployeeEntity> employees = new ArrayList<DepartmentEmployeeEntity>();
```

### entity class for BSU_EMPLOYEE

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "BSU_EMPLOYEE")
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "externalID", column =@Column(name="MemberInternalKey",insertable = false,updatable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "internalID", column =@Column(name="EmployeeInternalKey"))})


    public class DepartmentEmployeeEntity extends BaseEntityDto {    

        @EmbeddedId
        private DepartmentEmployeeIdClass idClass;

            @ManyToOne
        private DepartmentEntity departmentEntity;
```

### COMPOSITE KEY CLASS

```
 @Embeddable
    public class DepartmentEmployeeIdClass implements Serializable {


        @Column(name = "MemberInternalKey" ,unique = false,nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
        private int memberInternalKey;


        @Column(name = "EmployeeInternalKey")
        private int employeeInternalKey;
```

Comment: This is quite a lot of code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, thanks for your guidance , tried to reduce the code ,can you please help if it makes sense to you